# Form fields created via Ajax are missing element attributes

Tags: 8, forms

I have a custom form with a date field and a series of textfields and number fields. The textfields and number fields are dynamically re-created via an ajax callback function that runs whenever the date field changes, because the default values of the textfields and number fields will depend on the value of the date field.

The form runs this function once upon loading, which works fine, it returns the $form object with all expected values in the fields.

However, whenever that same function is called again by the ajax trigger, almost all of the attributes of the dynamic fields are missing. The `data-drupal-selector`, `id`, `name`, and `value` attributes are gone. The default values do not appear. The `for` attribute of labels also disappears.

I have noticed that this is not true of `table` form API elements and only seems to affect input elements and labels.

Is this the expected behaviour? Is it avoidable?

Example:

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form['date'] = array(
        '#type' => 'date',
        '#ajax' => [
            'callback' => '::dateCallback',
            'wrapper' => 'wrapper',
        ],
        '#default_value' => date("Y-m-d")
    );
    $form['wrapper'] = [
        '#type' => 'container',
        '#attributes' => ['id' => 'wrapper'],
    ];
    $this->dateCallback($form, $form_state);
    return $form;
}

/**
 * Implements callback for Ajax event on date selection.
 *
 * @param array $form
 *   From render array.
 * @param \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state
 *   Current state of form.
 *
 * @return array
 *   Date selection section of the form.
 */
public function dateCallback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    //insert logic to determine value of a variable called $field1    

    $form['wrapper']['options'] = array(
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#attributes' => array('class' => array('options'))
    );
    $form['wrapper']['options']['field1'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => "Field 1",
        '#default_value' => $field1
    );
    $form['wrapper']['table'] = array(
        '#type' => 'table',
        '#title' => t('Table'),
        '#header' => array("H1", "H2", "H3"),
        '#attributes' => array('class' => array('custom-table'))
    );
    //insert logic to generate table rows
    return $form['wrapper'];
}
```

(Note: In order to get ajax to work with date fields, as per [my previous question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/235855/adding-ajax-to-a-date-field), I had to apply a Drupal patch. However, I am pretty sure this issue is not related to this patch, as the problem persists even if I attach the callback to another form APi element like a Select dropdown.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a good idea to invoke the callback in the form build to include the form elements of the callback in $form to allow the form builder to process these elements. But then you overwrite the same form elements that the form builder has processed with the unprocessed form elements when the ajax triggers the callback.

Solution: Move all form elements in buildForm(). Leave the callback empty, only return the wrapper part of the form.

Comment: Thanks, I'm giving this a try. So do you mean I should move all my field definitions to buildForm()? If so, should I keep the logic that determines the value of the field in the callback function? I'm not sure where else I would put it, but having $form['wrapper']['options']['field1']['#default_value'] = $field1; in the callback does not seem to change the value now.

Comment: Put everything in buildForm(), determine the triggering element with `$form_state->getTriggeringElement()`, if you need to react on ajax actions, don't do this in the callback.

Comment: Thanks, I see what you mean. I moved everything to buildForm() and it is working as expected. My only problem now is that it always thinks the value of the date element is null.

Comment: Just read the previous question. For testing or as workaround you could place a button beside the date field to trigger the ajax.

Comment: Hmm, none of my code which depended on the date seems to be working at all now, not even the table code. The buildForm() function can't seem to detect the $form_state value of any field defined within that same function.

Comment: That's my last comment about, I don't trust the date field ajax code to validate the values right. Start with the most basic ajax trigger, which is a button with an `#ajax` key. Then the values of all form fields should appear in $form_state.

Comment: I tried it with a Select element, I made some simple code that put the value of that element in one of the text fields, but it's being populated with a null value.

Comment: Is NULL in $form_state or in the populated field value? If it is the latter, then it could be you are trying to set '#value', but you need to set '#default_value'

Comment: My code in buildForm for it is: $field1 = $form_state->getValue('sel'); and then: $form['wrapper']['options']['field1']['#default_value'] = $field1;

Comment: Hmm, okay, I had this all wrong. I forgot ddl was a thing. It looked like it was executing the code that's supposed to happen when the form state value is null. So it knows what the form state value is, it just doesn't seem to be updating the field value via #default_value when told to. I'll have to investigate this more.