# How do I change the default value of a field with AJAX?

Tags: 8, forms

Related to my previous question: [Form fields created via Ajax are missing element attributes](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/236942/form-fields-created-via-ajax-are-missing-element-attributes)

I have a date field and a series of text and number fields which need their default values to change based on the value of the date field. I've updated my code so it functions this way:

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form['date'] = array(
        '#type' => 'date',
        '#ajax' => [
            'callback' => '::dateCallback',
            'wrapper' => 'wrapper',
        ],
        '#default_value' => date("Y-m-d")
    );
    $form['wrapper'] = [
        '#type' => 'container',
        '#attributes' => ['id' => 'wrapper'],
    ];

    //insert logic to determine value of a variable called $field1    
    $form['wrapper']['options'] = array(
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#attributes' => array('class' => array('options'))
    );
    $form['wrapper']['options']['field1'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => "Field 1",
        '#value' => $field1
    );
    $form['wrapper']['table'] = array(
        '#type' => 'table',
        '#title' => t('Table'),
        '#header' => array("H1", "H2", "H3"),
        '#attributes' => array('class' => array('custom-table'))
    );
    //insert logic to generate table rows
    return $form;
}

/**
 * Implements callback for Ajax event on date selection.
 *
 * @param array $form
 *   From render array.
 * @param \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state
 *   Current state of form.
 *
 * @return array
 *   Date selection section of the form.
 */
public function dateCallback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    return $form['wrapper'];
}
```

There are 2 problems I am having with this:

1) Implementing it in this way, such that the `#value` property is changed when the date field is changed, technically works, however if the user then chooses to modify any of the textfield values, that is not reflected in the `$form_state` object and is overridden by whatever `#value` was last set to in `buildForm()`.

2) I have also tried using `#default_value` instead, but the value in the field will not update if it already has something in it (which it usually does from the first time `#default_value` is set in `buildForm()`). I have seen some threads like [this one](https://www.drupal.org/node/1024962#comment-4021826) suggesting to unset the value in `$form_state` before setting `#default_value` again, however all such suggestions are for Drupal 7 where `$form_state` is a completely different data structure.

Is there a known way to do what I am trying to accomplish?

Update: I tried method 2 again by adding `$form_state->unsetValue('field1');` before declaring `$form['wrapper']['options']['field1']`, but this did not change the behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Method 1 setting `#value` does indeed make it impossible for the user to input data.

So the method 2 setting `#default_value` is I think still the best approach. As the old trick from D7, unsetting the value in $form_state, doesn't work anymore, you can try this one:

Create the field in a subkey, which is incremented for each request. Set the property `#tree` on the first level of the field, so you get back the field value as array `[$key => $value]`:

```
$form['wrapper']['options']['field1']['#tree'] = TRUE;

if ($form_state->hasValue('field1')) {
  $key = key($form_state->getValue('field1'));
  $value_field1 = current($form_state->getValue('field1')); 
  $key++;
}
else {
  $key = '0';
  $value_field1 = NULL;
}

// insert logic to determine new field value
// but check, if there is user input in $value_field1, that you don't want to overwrite

$form['wrapper']['options']['field1'][$key] = [
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => 'Text 1',
  '#default_value' => $value_field1,
];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've implemented this code and according to my debug logs it is working fine and setting #default_value to the appropriate value. However on the form it is only ever showing the form fields that would be at $key = 0 (confirmed by inspecting element attributes). Is this the expected behaviour? I am not sure how to get it to show the fields that would be at index $key instead.

Comment: Drupal renders all keys in a form render array, I see no reason why this is not happening. Btw. there is only ever one version of the field, because on a rebuild the field with the last key is not built again. If you have on a rebuild in an ajax request still the field in key 0 then the key didn't increment.

Comment: Oops, it was a typo in one of my $form indexes.... This is working perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: @4k4 You might consider refactoring the use of the `each` function, it's been deprecated and using it is highly discouraged

Comment: @Clive, thanks, this is indeed deprecated in PHP 7.2

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to do the same: Set #value property on ajax callback.

```
    <?php

    namespace Drupal\drupal_miseries\Form;

    use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
    use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

    class AjaxResponse extends FormBase {
      protected $ts_values = [
        'ts1' => [
          'values1' => [
            'id' => 1,
            'description' => 'Valor1',
            'status' => '1',
          ],
          'values2' => [
              'id' => 2,
              'description' => 'Valor2',
              'status' => 2,
          ],
        ],
      ];

      public function getFormId() {
        return 'AjaxResponseForm';
      }

      public function ajaxTableSelect(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        $element = $form_state->getTriggeringElement();
        if (isset($element) && $element['#type'] == 'checkbox') {
          $check_value = $element['#return_value'];
          $textfield_ts = $this->ts_values['ts1'][$check_value]['description'];
          $form['ts_textfield']['textfield']['#value'] = $textfield_ts;
        }

        return $form['ts_textfield'];
      }

      public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

        $form['ts_container'] = [
          '#type' => 'container',
          '#attributes' => ['id' => 'ts-container'],
        ];

        $header = [
          'id' => $this->t('ID'),
          'description' => $this->t('Description'),
          'status' => $this->t('Status'),
        ];

        $form['tableselect'] = [
          '#type' => 'tableselect',
          '#description' => $this->t('Test Tableselect'),
          '#header' => $header,
          '#options' => $this->ts_values['ts1'],
          '#empty' => $this->t('No values'),
          '#ajax' => [
            'callback' => [$this, 'ajaxTableSelect'],
            'wrapper' => 'ts-textfield',
          ],
        ];

        $form['ts_textfield'] = [
          '#type' => 'container',
          '#attributes' => ['id' => 'ts-textfield'],
        ];

        $form['ts_textfield']['textfield'] = [
          '#type' => 'textfield',
          '#description' => $this->t('Value fill by ajax'),
          '#title' => $this->t('Ajax Textfield'),
        ];

        $form['actions'] = [
          '#type' => 'actions',
        ];

        $form['action']['submit'] = [
          '#type' => 'submit',
          '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
        ];

        return $form;
      }

      public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        dpm($form_state->getValue('tableselect'));
        dpm($form_state->getValue('textfield'));
      }
    }
```

When you click on any tableselect checkbox, textfield is set with checkbox value => if you click 'submit' checkbox value is assigned to textfield.

When you click on any tableselect checkbox, textfield is set with checkbox value => if you change textfield manually and click 'submit' new value will be assigned to textfield.

but.......Is this the correct way to do that?

Answer (score -1):

A solution to append a default value to the field after callback but with option for user to change input:

add the value to field attributes: *'#attributes' => array('value' => array($form_state->getValue('option2'))),*

```
        $o = [];
    $form['option1'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#size' => 1,
        '#options' => ['a' => 'A', 'b' => 'B'],
        '#title' => $this->t('option 1'),
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#ajax' => array(
            'callback' => array($this, 'next'),
            'wrapper' => 'option2',
        ),
    );

    if ($form_state->getValue('option1') == 'a') {
        $o = [1 => 'one', 2 => 'two'];
    }
    if ($form_state->getValue('option1') == 'b') {
        $o = [3 => 'three', 4 => 'four'];
    }

    $form['option2'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#size' => 1,
        '#options' => $o,
        '#title' => t('option 2'),
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#prefix' => "<div id='option2'",
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
        '#ajax' => array(
            'callback' => array($this, 'get_data'),
            'wrapper' => 'data',
        ),
    );

    $form['data'] = [
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#id' => 'test',
        '#title' => t("choice") . " " . $form_state->getValue('option2'),
        '#default_value' => $form_state->getValue('option2'),
        '#size' => 5,
        '#attributes' => array('value' => array($form_state->getValue('option2'))),
        '#prefix' => "<div id='data'",
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
    ];

    $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => $this->t('Test'),
        '#suffix' => ''
    );

    return $form;
}

/**
 * callback functions
 */
public function next(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    return $form['option2'];
}

public function get_data(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    return $form['data'];
}

public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

}

public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    dpm($form_state->getValue('data'));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I've solved this by using the AJAX callback to reload the page, rather than return the form. For example:

```
$path = '/path/to/form';
$response = new AjaxResponse();
$response->addCommand(new RedirectCommand($path));
return $response;
```

It's slower than returning the form, but is a lot less code, especially if you're talking about a complex form with a lot of default values.