# Controlling a dependent field in a multi-instance paragraph

Tags: 8, forms, ajax, paragraphs

The fields below are part of the node/add node/edit forms of my custom node type.

[image]

The paragraph `field_para_city` contain one `field_city`. (I later need to add other fields in the paragraph).

The user can add multiple instances from `field_para_city`.

`field_city` has an allowed_values_function defined in a YML file, which returns all possible cities from all countries.

I created a `class MyNodeTypeForm extends NodeForm`, with a `public function buildForm()`. This function adds AJAX to `field_country` so that when it changes (i.e. the user chooses a country) it (re-)populates all the **existing** instances of field_city (inside the `field_para_city` instances) with corresponding list of cities (e.g., London and Cardiff for the UK).

In MY_MODULE.module, I added the following so that the above code is executed on the node/add and node/edit forms.

```
function MY_MODULE_entity_type_alter(array &$entity_types) {
  $handlers = $entity_types['node']->get('handlers');
  $handlers['form']['default']  = 'Drupal\MY_MODULE\Form\MyNodeTypeForm';
  $handlers['form']['edit']     = 'Drupal\MY_MODULE\Form\MyNodeTypeForm';
  $entity_types['node']->set('handlers', $handlers);
}
```

All works fine, **except when the user add or remove instances of `field_para_city`** ("Add city" or "Remove"), then all instances of the `field_para_city` are refreshed and `field_city` instances inside them are reset to the allowed values (all cities), ignoring the state of `field_country`.

The user would then need to re-select from `field_country` to get the correct cities again.

I found that although adding/removing a `field_para_city` triggered the above mentioned `buildForm()` function, the `$form_state->getValue('field_country')` was then empty, unlike when `buildForm()` is triggered through the `field_country` AJAX.

I tried to capture the state of `field_country` in the `field_city`'s allowed_values_function, so that the allowed options are dynamically and directly set based on the user choice of country, but `$form_state` was not recognised there.

---

I know this is an incorrect approach!

What is the correct better approach to implement this simple use case?

Comment: A question, have you tried or are you using https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields ?

Comment: I thought about it. It allows changing field value based on another field's value, but I actually need something  beyond that: the dependent field options should be programmatically populated taking into account also some existing contents and settings in the website.

Comment: I believe buildForm() runs everytime the AJAX handler is called.  Therefore, many people opt to have the complete logic in buildForm() and then the ajax handler simply returns the $form back without touching it (maybe setting $form_state->setRebuild(FALSE);) . This thread may have relevant info on ajax forms: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/236942/form-fields-created-via-ajax-are-missing-element-attributes

Comment: I actually have a different problem. The AJAX re-builds the form after being triggered by changes in `field_country` here. But what I need is a mechanism to rebuild the form (or at least the dependent field) when a new dependent field is being added. So the trigger here is the creation of the dependent field, at which I need to access the value of the controlling field.

Comment: May I invite the experts to help answering this question?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work using a different approach; instead of overriding the NodeFrom, I used [hook_field_widget_WIDGET_TYPE_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_WIDGET_TYPE_form_alter/8.6.x) and edited the `subform` array there.
Example:

`/**
 * Implements hook_field_widget_WIDGET_TYPE_form_alter().
 */
function MY_MODULE_field_widget_entity_reference_paragraphs_form_alter(&$element, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $context)
{
  //Logic to exclude other Paragraph types
  if ($element['#paragraph_type'] !== 'YOUR_PARAGRAPH_TYPE'){ //e.g. cities
    return;
  }
  $element['subform']['field_places']['#states'] = [
    'visible' => [
      [
        //It worked for me with the ID of the select, I think you can use the name also
        '#edit-field-cities-0-subform-field-city' => array('value' => 'Cairo'),
      ]
    ]
  ];
}`

When I add another paragraph, the ajax is fired and the selection is still preserved.
I haven't tried with other Ajax fields present though.

Comment: Thanks for this. However, I'm not sure how it exactly solves the problem. In my question, the problem is when I add another paragraph that the allowed values (options) in the list in the existing paragraph are reset but the selection is actually preserved.

Comment: By the way, did you mean `field_country` instead of `field_places`? If so, I wasn't able to get the AJAX of the `field_county` to be fired..

Comment: Oh sorry, it seems I misunderstood your question. I tried applying a different approach with the same hook but it didn't work for me neither. The fields kept being deselected with addition of new field item. `field_places` is totally irrelevant to your issue. Sorry again

Comment: No problem! I really appreciate your answer though!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by setting **unique id** for each dependent select box & replace its options whenever the parent select box is changed by setting this **unique id** as ajax wrapper in parent

**These are three important things to make it working**

A. Set **unique id** for child select box (dependent)

B. On parent select box set **unique id**(same uniqueid which is set in child dropdown) as [#ajax][wrapper], use [#ajax][method] as **html** .

C. In the Ajax callback use **HtmlCommand()** as Ajax response .

```
<?php

 use \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
 use Drupal\Core\Ajax\HtmlCommand;
 use Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse;
/**  
 * Implements hook_field_widget_WIDGET_TYPE_form_alter().  
*/  
 function modulename_field_widget_entity_reference_paragraphs_form_alter(&$element, &$form_state, $context) {
 if ($element['#paragraph_type'] == 'country_select') {
  $form_state->setRebuild(FALSE);
// Generating Unique id for each state by using parents & delta  
$gen_id = 'edit-state-';
foreach ($element['subform']['field_state']['widget']['#parents'] as $value) {
   $gen_id .= is_integer($value) ? "-". $value : "";
}
$gen_id .= "-".$element['subform']['field_state']['widget']["#delta"];
$element['subform']['field_state']['widget']['#attributes']["id"] = $gen_id;
 // Add ajax 
 $element['subform']['field_country']['widget']['#ajax'] = [
      'callback' => 'update_state_dropdown', //ajax call back
      'event' => 'change',
      'method' => 'html', // html method
      'wrapper' => $gen_id, // unique id
      'progress' => [
            'type' => 'throbber',
             'message' => NULL,
            ],
      ];
  // Set default value options for state when the country_select  paragraph is loaded     
  $default_country = $element['subform']['field_country']['widget']['#default_value'];
  if(isset($default_country[0])) {
     $options = get_state_options_by_country($default_country[0]); // replace with you function
    $element['subform']['field_state']['widget']['#options'] = $options;
  }
 }
} 

// Ajax call back

function update_state_dropdown(array &$element, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
 $triggeringElement = $form_state->getTriggeringElement();
 $value = $triggeringElement['#value'];
 $options = get_state_options_by_country($value); // replace with you function
 $wrapper_id = $triggeringElement["#ajax"]["wrapper"];
 $renderedField = '';
 foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
   $renderedField .= "<option value='".$key."'>".$value."</option>";
 }
 $response = new AjaxResponse();
 $response->addCommand(new HtmlCommand("#".$wrapper_id, $renderedField));
 return $response;
}
```

as per [link](http://btobac.com/blog/create-dependent-dropdowns-paragraph-field-multiple-values-drupal-8). it also have github link for source

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [Business Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/business_rules) module?  It provides [this functionality](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/business-rules/advanced-usage/dependent-field).  You may need a patch from [Add AJAX support to Paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/business_rules/issues/3040253) if it hasn't been merged yet.